# in postgres, can one optimize a table across partitions?

Tags: postgresql

in a database with many companies, segregating them using `schema` and `search_path`

almost all access comes at the company level, that is, limited to a single schema.  some data-warehouse and accounting functions need to scan all schema.

for this problem, per @horse_with_no_name's most excellent suggestion, using the schema themselves as partitions.  for example

```
create table global.usr(
    usr_id int primary key,  // these will be unique across all partitions
    name varchar );

create table cmp1.usr(
    usr_id int primary key,
) inherits( global.usr );

create table cmp2.usr( 
    ....
```

if we populate

```
insert into cmp1 usr values( 11, 'eleven' );
insert into cmp1 usr values( 12, 'twelve' );

insert into cmp2 usr values( 21, 'twenty-one' );
insert into cmp2 usr values( 22, 'twenty-two' );

insert into cmp3 usr values( 31, 'thirty-one' );
insert into cmp3 usr values( 32, 'thirty-two' );
```

this works beautifully at the schema level:

```
set search_path = 'global';
select count(1) from t;   => 6

set search_path = 'cmp1, global';
select count(1) from t;   => 2

set search_path = 'cmp1, cmp2, global';
select count(1) from t;   => 4

set search_path = 'global, cmp1';
select count(1) from t;   => 6
```

the question is whether there is any way to optimize at the global level.  for example, would it be possible to create an index on global.usr_id that would span all partitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the question is whether there is any way to optimize at the global level. for example, would it be possible to create an index on global.usr_id that would span all partitions?

Sadly the answer is "No" - global indexes [are not currently supported](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Table_partitioning#Executor)

Comment: I can understand why - it's a bitch of a problem - but because of the usefulness of pg's partitioned tables, would be dynamite to have